# footer position wrong because of height:100%

Tags: html, css, height, footer, positioning

I found quite a lot of people asking similar question, but mine seems to be a different problem.
This is the arrangement of my div.

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <header>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-1">
    </div>
    <div class="content-2">
    </div>
    <div class="content-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every class except for header and footer has  `height:100%;`   including <html> & <body>

Class content-1, content-2, content-3 has  `background-size:cover;`  
because I want the background to be full page.

I don't have any issue, *as long as* all my content is inside the class "content". However, now I want to add <footer> underneath the class "content". So the <footer> position is supposed to be below content-3, but it appear below content-1 instead. Is there a way to add a <footer> but not inside the class "content"?

**What I have tried:**

- set <footer> to  `position:absolute; bottom:0;`  doesn't work. Problem persists.
- set  `overflow:auto`  to class "content" will set footer to the
  correct position, but now I have two scroll bars.

[image for visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPPEP.jpg)

Comment: Class one, two and three have float style?

Comment: To answer MR.Mostafa, no float involve, and I don't plan to use any float. This is a link to the simplified code. https://jsfiddle.net/80cL2heu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.content {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean placing that code in the "footer"? It works if I want footer always stick to the bottom of the screen, but I don't want that. I want the footer section appear only if user scroll to the very bottom of the page. Here is a link to the simplified code. jsfiddle.net/80cL2heu

Comment: Try adding 'display: inline;' to 'content' class

Comment: adding 'display: inline;' works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this 

.content {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't work, the code doesn't seems to have any effect. Also, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Can you share website URL?

Comment: This is a link to the simplified code. https://jsfiddle.net/80cL2heu/